# Excel formulas to values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

Is there a way to make the number that a formula returns a value without using the Cut and Paste method.

Because I'd have to do that on about a hundred different cells every day. So Cut and Paste isn't a viable method. Is there not some shortcut or some weird way I can avoid this.

To simplify... I need B1 to = A4 I then will update A4 adding the new days data and I will then need to have B2 = A4 - the old value of B1.

For this to work B1 needs to have become a value and not a formula referencing A4 because I need to be able to update A4 everyday. So after each day the next cell needs to become a value.

Remember I can't copy and paste again & again

Can someone Help me!

Comment: You will need VBA in a worksheet_Change Event

Comment: Christ. Am yet to learn about VBA's yet. Is what you're suggesting complicated to learn.
Thanks for response. @ScottCraner

Comment: `complicated` is a personal ranking.  For some, no not very complicated, for others it is akin to learning calculus without first knowing Algebra.

Comment: Thankyou for your help, I would upvote you if i knew how.
In the nicest way possible I hope I don't ever see you again but there is a real possibility I will be back very soon.

Off to go learn algebra.

Comment: @Louis, you mean to say every next day you need A4 to be updated by B2 has old value of B1 !!

Answer (score 1):

This assumes the column **B** and cell **A4** start completely empty.  Place the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A4 As Range, B1 As Range, n As Long
    Set A4 = Range("A4")
    Set B1 = Range("B1")
    If Intersect(A4, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If B1 = "" Then
            B1 = A4
        Else
            n = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            Cells(n + 1, "B").Value = Cells(n, "B").Value - A4
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to **install** and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 0):

With something that has a set pattern like this, one can create a Named Range ("NR"), using relative references, and carefully picking the active cell while creating the Named Range, then use that each day to Paste Values.

By `set pattern` I mean that if July 1 "takes place" in cells B1, H4, and XX9, then July 2 takes place immediately underneath those cells:  B2, H4, and XX10. And so on through any given month. One would NEVER have it go to B2, H38, XX10 for the second day.

You can select a Named Range in the box to the left of the formula editing bar. The one that shows your active cell. Once selected, you would just `Copy`, then `Paste|Special|Values` in a single step and be done. So select the Named Range in the box, then copy and paste. All done.

To make it work, use relative references (no $B$1:  use B1) so it will do that if in B1, but if B2 is selected it would do B2 instead.

The other step to make that work is to make the first cell your active cell during the creation of the NR. If you are a cell under it, it would select B2, not B1!

Create the string that lists the cells in the range however you hve to, even if you have to type all "about a hundred" cell addresses. It's just once. Plenty of tricks taking advantage of putting strings together can help out. Once done, don't check it by examining the little bits of text! Select it and look to see if it selected all the right cells. Vastly easier to accurately check that way:  akin to comparing two pages, character-by-character to see if they are the same vs. placing one over the other, holding them up to a light, and seeing if there are any differences. The latter is not only much easier, but more accurate.

Create the string outside the NR function, then copy it and paste it into the Value box for the new NR. No typing outside the easy, tool-filled, environment of a normal spreadsheet page.

Lastly, a Windows weirdness, not an Excel one:  the LAST cell address in the NR is the one it will start in, not the FIRST one. It will roll over to the first one next if you `TAB` through, but... WHAT? So list the cells starting with #2, #3, ... #last one, #1 and it will have the one you wish to first be the active cell selected.

Here, that doesn't matter to your copying and pasting, onlyto "just where you are" for beginning further work, when this is done. Other uses though, other spreadsheets, it could be handy to consider.

To reiterate, each day you'd select A cell amongst the ones to paste values in, then select the range, then copy and paste. That's all. No macros needed so no learning needed and the range can easily be edited or added to if anything changes.